# SQL query table with subquery range from second table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

I have two tables, table one has two ranges that i use to query a second table, i want to do this in a single query so far i have the two individual queries but cant seem to find out how to use them together.

[This is table one, with the ranges that are from_book_id, from_chapter, to_book_id and to_chapter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgp0J.png)

This is the query i use to get the desired row:

```
SELECT * FROM plans WHERE plans.day = 1 AND plans.plan_id  = 1
```

[This is the second table with the data to filter with tables one range.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGyhy.png)

I use this to get the desired result from this table

```
SELECT verse.* FROM verse WHERE (verse.book_id >= 1 AND verse.book_id <= 1) AND (verse.chapter >= 1 AND verse.chapter <= 5))
```

---

To clarify, i need to use the resulting ranges from the first table as query for the second as so:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM t1 WHERE (t1.book_id >= t2.from_book_id AND t1.book_id <= t2.to_book_id) AND (t1.chapter >= t2.from_chapter AND t1.chapter <= t2.to_chapter))
```

I hope this explanation is clear enough and i thank you all in advance.

---

**EDIT**

I seem to have come across some special cases in the query, although it works perfectly fine when i come across ranges like:

```
from_book_id:1, from_chapter:1, to_book_id:1, to_chapter:5
```

That range returns the desired result but when the range changes from one book to another like so:

```
from_book_id:1, from_chapter:5, to_book_id:2, to_chapter:5
```

This means it needs to get everything from book 1 chapter number 5 to the last chapter of book 1 and continue on book 2 until chapter number 5.

These cases break the query and returns null, i would really appreciate if you can help me with this one.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TRY THIS:** Hope it will provide you the exact output what you want. It will query `verse` table data based on `plans` table condition

```
SELECT * --you can shorten the columns by defining the required column names
FROM plans p
INNER JOIN verse v ON v.book_id BETWEEN p.from_book_id AND p.to_book_id
    AND v.chapter BETWEEN p.from_chapter AND p.to_chapter
WHERE p.day = 1 AND p.plan_id  = 1
```

**For Updated Requirement:** We can use `UNION`

```
SELECT * --you can shorten the columns by defining the required column names
FROM plans p
INNER JOIN verse v ON v.book_id = p.from_book_id
    AND v.chapter >= p.from_chapter
WHERE p.day = 1 AND p.plan_id  = 1
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM plans p
INNER JOIN verse v ON v.book_id = p.to_book_id
    AND v.chapter <= p.to_chapter
WHERE p.day = 1 AND p.plan_id  = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what i needed.

Comment: Hi Susang, thanks again for the help but i encountered some cases that from the plans table (this one holds the ranges) that returns null, i edited the question so you can see the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: I have added new query to achieve your updated requirement so please try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cortition join type to get  the result,

Please try  the below, hope this helps.

```
select a.* 
FROM  verse a
    , plans b 
where 
     a.book_id between  b.From_book_id and b.to_book_id
and  a.chapter between b.from_chapter and b.to_chapter
```